# R not running on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, r

I installed R 4.2.1 on by new Ubuntu 22.04 installation (using ZFS filesystem). The installation worked without error, and I can confirm that R is indeed installed with `R --version` which outputs the following:

```
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23) -- "Funny-Looking Kid"
Copyright (C) 2022 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under the terms of the
GNU General Public License versions 2 or 3.
For more information about these matters see
https://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
```

However, when I try to execute R from the terminal (e.g., `user@computer:~$ R`), nothing happens. If I try executing `R --verbose` the following text is output, however R still does not launch:

```
'verbose' and 'quietly' are both true; being verbose then ..
now dyn.load("/usr/lib/R/library/methods/libs/methods.so") ...
```

Also tried and failed:

- `sudo R`
- `sudo -i R`
- `Rscript test.R` where test.R contains `print("Hello, World!")`

Any further suggestions on troubleshooting?

Comment: Does `Rscript` instead of `R` work?

Comment: `R` is console mode. `Rscript` is for command line execution. `R` should end in a `>` where you can type commands.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Using `Rscript` to run a .R file with a simple print statement does not work either. No errors (that I can see) are thrown, it just doesn't output anything.

Comment: so .... what did you install? `r-base`? `r-base-core`?

Comment: `R version 4.2.1` There is something wrong there. Ubuntu 22.04 installs `4.1.2  (2021-11-01) -- "Bird Hippie"`. I installed r-base-core and DO get a `<`

Comment: Perhaps you have `R` aliased to something that makes it non-interactive? What does `type -a R` say?

Comment: @Rinzwind I installed r-base and r-base-dev from https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-22-04. Does not work if I install from ubuntu apt repo either.

Comment: @steeldriver
`R is /usr/bin/R` and `R is /bin/R`

Comment: When I try to launch RStudio from the terminal, I get the following error (which I imagine is related): `ERROR R did not return any output when queried for directory location information`

Comment: Update: seems to be the installation of the Citrix Receiver application. If I uninstall that, `R` works fine. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

@Brigadeiro

I had also been experiencing problems recently. My google chrome would not load (it would give the new tab page that would be in the loading state, but would never load), as well as having my R not running (and in turn, Rstudio would not run).

I took your advice and uninstalled Citrix Receiver and that fixed both problems. I presume there is some connection between these errors and the Citrix Receiver. I had previously tried to uninstall and reinstall both R and Chrome with no change in the failure to load.

Comment: Strange behavior indeed, but it worked by uninstalling icaclient on Ubuntu 22.04 thanks. `sudo apt remove icaclient`, `sudo apt purge icaclient`

Comment: Does anyone know whay is this happening ?